# Как правильно расширять функционал класса С#? паттерн Стратегия?

Tags: c#, шаблон-стратегия

Здравствуйте. Осваиваю понемногу C# и ООП как таковое. Хотелось бы понять как правильно расширять функционал класса. Предположим есть объект класса Context который должен будет постепенно дорабатываться. К нему нужно присоединять интерфейсы и их реализации (причем возможно несколько реализаций одного и того же интерфейса). В общем-то я сначала сам пришел к такому решению которое описано ниже, потом оказалось что это очень близко к шаблону Стратегия.

(Если конкретно хочу (в качестве учебной задачи) написать игрушку - типа пазла и постепенно дорабатывать ее - общим планируется система уровней/подуровней, а поведение должно меняться)

Может быть есть какие-то более удачные/правильные шаблоны для решения этой задачи. И вообще как это правильно делается? Может правильнее использовать методы расширения? К сожалению сам с шаблонами "на Вы" пока.

На всякий случай абстрактный пример

```
public interface IAdditionMetods
{
    void ShowSome();
}

public class TAdditionMetods : IAdditionMetods
{
    public void ShowSome()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something");
    }
}

public class TAdditionMetods2 : IAdditionMetods
{
    public void ShowSome()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something else");
    }
}

public class TContext
{
    private IAdditionMetods NewMetods { get; set; }
    private IAdditionMetods NewMetods2 { get; set; }

    public TContext(IAdditionMetods AdditionMethods, IAdditionMetods AdditionMethods2)
    {
        NewMetods = AdditionMethods;
        NewMetods2 = AdditionMethods2;
    }

    public void ExecuteSomething()
    {
        NewMetods.ShowSome();
        NewMetods2.ShowSome();
    }
}



public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TContext Context;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Context = new TContext(new TAdditionMetods(), new TAdditionMetods2());
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Context.ExecuteSomething();
    }

}
```

Comment: "расширять функционал" вам поможет декоратор, стратегия занимается другим. разберитесь в том, чего вы хотите)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала давйте разберемся, что значит расширить функционал класса, а что значит его изменить. 
Изменение функционала класса - это (в моем понимании, конечно) изменение его изначально заложенного поведения. Контракта, если хотите. Например, у вас есть класс для рассылки писем, который просто отправляет переданное ему письмо.

```
public class EmailSender
{
    public void SendEmail(IEmailMessage message)
    {
        // Просто отметим, что внутри метода что то происходит
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending {message.Title} to {message.To}");          
    }
}
```

Само сообщение:

```
public interface IEmailMessage
{
    string Title { get; }
    string Body { get; }
    string To { get; }
}

public class EmailMessage : IEmailMessage
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Body { get; private set; }
    public string To { get; private set; }

    public EmailMessage(string to, string title, string body)
    {
        To = to;
        Title = title;
        Body = body;
    }
}
```

Добавление в этот же класс возможности высылать письма по заданному графику - это изменение его поведения, так как класс изначально на это не расчитан. Навешивание новых интерфейсов на класс - это также изменение поведения класса.

Теперь пговорим о расширении функционала класса. Тут тоже есть разные возможности, например, рассмотрим тот же класс `EmailSender`, но на этот раз добавим интерфейс `IEmailSender`. Это не будет считаться изменением функционала, так как мы не добавили новый интерфейс классу, а выделили интерфейс из него. То есть код внутри класса не изменился.

```
public interface IEmailSender
{
    void SendEmail(IEmailMessage message);
}

public class EmailSender: IEmailSender
{
    public void SendEmail(IEmailMessage message)
    {
        // Просто отметим, что внутри метода что то происходит
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending {message.Title} to {message.To}");
    }
}
```

Одним из способов расширить функционал класса, не изменив его, является декоратор. Допустим, нам понадобилось добавить логгирование при отправке сообщения. Мы запросто можем написать вот такой класс-декоратор:

```
public class EmailSenderLogger : IEmailSender
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    private IEmailSender _inner;

    public EmailSenderLogger(ILogger logger, IEmailSender inner)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void SendEmail(IEmailMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            _inner.SendEmail(message);
            _logger.Info($"Email {message} sended.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error($"Cannot send {message}", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Простенькая реализация логгера

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void Error(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{message} - {ex}");
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Как видно, изначальный класс не был изменен, но его функционал был расширен за счет декоратора. Но давайте не будем на этом останавливаться. У нас же речь про стратегию, верно? Теперь представим, что в случае неудачи отправки письма, мы хотим произвести ещё несколько попыток отправки, прежде чем упасть с исключением. Для того, чтобы это сделать, нам понадобится интерфейс для стратегии выполнения операции.

```
public interface IOperationExecuteStrategy
{
    void Execute(Action operation);
}
```

Напишем наивную реализацию:

```
public class RetryOperationExecuteStrategy : IOperationExecuteStrategy
{
    int _numAttempts;

    public RetryOperationExecuteStrategy(int numAttempts)
    {
        _numAttempts = numAttempts;
    }

    public void Execute(Action operation)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        for(var i=0; i<_numAttempts; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                operation();
                return;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        throw new AggregateException("Unable to execute operation", exceptions);
    }
}
```

отлично, у нас теперь есть стратегия, но что же тогда будет контекстом? В нашем случае это будет просто ещё один декоратор:

```
public class EmailSenderRetrier : IEmailSender
{
    private IOperationExecuteStrategy _executeStrategy;
    private IEmailSender _inner;

    public EmailSenderRetrier(IOperationExecuteStrategy executeStrategy, IEmailSender inner)
    {       
        _inner = inner;
        _executeStrategy = executeStrategy;
    }

    public void SendEmail(IEmailMessage message)
    {
        _executeStrategy.Execute(() => _inner.SendEmail(message));
    }
}
```

Теперь, комбинируя представленные классы, можно собрать класс, который будет предпринимать 5 попыток отправить емейл, и если все попытки будут неудачны, то все это попалет в лог. Обычно это делается средствами DI контейнера, но для наглядности я покажу как это делается руками:

```
var emailSender = new EmailSenderLogger(new Logger(), 
                        new EmailSenderRetrier(new RetryOperationExecuteStrategy(5), 
                                new EmailSender()));

// Успешно отработает и запишет успех в лог
emailSender.SendEmail(new EmailMessage("to@mail.demo", "title", "body"));

// упадет после 5 попыток и запишет неудачу в лог
emailSender.SendEmail(null);
```

Таким образом, я показал пару вариантов как расширить функционал класса, при этом не изменив его поведение.

Что касается вашего класса и шаблона Стратегия - сложно что либо понять без конкретных требований. Тут можно и GameManager использовать как контекст, а конкретную игру - как стратегию. И Игру - как контекст, а уровень как стратегию. И Уровень как контекст, а персонажей - как стратегию. Но, я надеюсь, внес хотя бы небольшую ясность в понимание принципа расширения функционала классов.