# Проинспектировать код калькулятора процентной ставки с учетом капитализации с проверками ввода

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, ввод, калькулятор

Я только начал изучать C#
Это простой калькулятор процентной ставки с учетом капитализации. По сути это была задача. которую я немного усложнил для большей практики, поэтому добавил проверки на ввод "Не цифры" \ "Не достаточно элементов ввода" и т.д.

Скажите, все ли в порядке? 
Это понятный код?
Просто хочу изначально писать относительно не коряво.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace zadacha_proc
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void InputResult(string userInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Calculate(userInput) + ".Руб");
        }
        public static double Calculate(string userInput)
        {
            // Попытка выполнить
            try
            {
                var result = userInput.Split();
                // Проверка длинны массива
                if (result.Length != 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введено не 3 начения");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Main();
                    Console.Clear();
                    return (0);
                }
                // Если длинна массива недостаточна
                else
                {
                    double summa = double.Parse(result[0]);
                    double proc = double.Parse(result[1]);
                    double time = double.Parse(result[2]);
                    return Math.Round(summa * Math.Pow((1 + proc / 1200), time));
                }
            }
            // Если попытка не удалась
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введены не цифры");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Main();
                return (0);
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Inter Summa / Procent / Mounth ");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            InputResult(userInput);
            Console.ResetColor();
            Main();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Коллеги в очередях проверки, внимание! Не стоит закрывать вопрос, речь в нём идёт о инспеции кода, это вполне допустимая тема на сайте (добавил метку, кто не в курсе - почитайте что в ней сказано).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В основе читаемого кода лежит разбиение ответственности классов/методов. По сути, чем короче метод / класс, тем проще понять конкретный кусок кода. Поэтому обычно при работе над проектами программист работает с большим количеством небольших классов.

Я не буду писать про принципы и практики, про это уже только ленивый не писал. Например, [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889202/179763).

Давайте поглядим на это на практике. Начем с малого - у вас есть разный тип вывода в консоль, например, ошибки вы красным выводите, обычные сообщения - белым. Также вы читаете с консоли и при этом каждый раз вам нудо проверять, ввел ли пользователь число или нет? А что, если вы однажды забудете проверить? Думаете, этой проверке место в калькуляторе? А что, если вы захотите читать/писать не в консоль, а, например, веб сервис или настольное приложение?

Ответ напрашивается сам собой - надо изолировать работу с консолью. Я разделил обязанности писать и читать в консоль, потому у меня получилось 2 класса:

Писатель будет иметь 2 метода, для записи информации и ошибки

```
public class ConsoleWriter
{
    public void WriteInfo(string message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void WriteError(string message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Читатель, соответственно, читает из консоли

```
public class ConsoleReader
{
    ConsoleWriter _writer;

    public ConsoleReader(ConsoleWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public double ReadDouble(string name)
    {
        double ret;
        _writer.WriteInfo($"Введите: {name}");
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ret))
            _writer.WriteError($"{name}: должно быть числом");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Далее, вы же пишете калькулятор, верно? Калькулятор должен работать только с тем функционалом, что требуется для расчета. Ему не надо читать/писать куда то, он только для того, чтобы выполнять конкретный расчет. Так появляется класс калькулятора

```
public class PercentCapitalCalculator
{
    public double Calculate(double summa, double proc, double time)
    {
        return Math.Round(summa * Math.Pow((1 + proc / 1200), time));
    }
}
```

Теперь надо собрать всю вашу логику. То есть считать что нужно, отправить калькулятору, вывести результат. Появляется класс логики

```
public class MainLogic
{
    ConsoleReader _reader;
    ConsoleWriter _writer;
    PercentCapitalCalculator _calculator;

    public MainLogic(ConsoleReader reader, ConsoleWriter writer, PercentCapitalCalculator calculator)
    {
        _reader = reader;
        _writer = writer;
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var summa = _reader.ReadDouble("сумма");
        var proc = _reader.ReadDouble("процент");
        var time = _reader.ReadDouble("время");

        _writer.WriteInfo($"сумма:{summa} процент:{proc} время:{time}");
        _writer.WriteInfo($"Результат: {_calculator.Calculate(summa, proc, time)} руб.");
    }
}
```

Точка входа же (функция main) предназначена только для того, чтобы подготовить все нужные классы и запустить логику. Место в коде, начальная функция, где готовятся и запускаются классы, называется корнем аггрегации. У нас она будет выглядеть так

```
static void Main()
{
    var writer = new ConsoleWriter();
    var reader = new ConsoleReader(writer);
    var calc = new PercentCapitalCalculator();
    var logic = new MainLogic(reader, writer, calc);
    logic.Run();
}
```

В итоге мы получаем набор классов, каждый из них выполняет только одну функцию и хорошо читается.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, это вполне типовая программа, она достаточно понятна (ну то есть не кишит огромным числом ошибок на квадратный сантиметр текста), хотя и есть куда улучшать.

Во-первых, обратите внимание на ваш блок catch. Он в общем-то работает, но этот кусок куда слабовато написан. Дело в том, что нужно указывать какие конкретные ошибки вы перехватываете, их может быть несколько - но у вас на всё реакция одна и та же. Причин попадания в блок catch может быть много, не обязательно "введены не цифры", но в показываете только одно сообщение "введены не цифры". Как только вы отловите другую ошибку и пользователь обратит ваше внимание, что программа выдаёт "не то" сообщение - вам придётся тратить время, разбираться (а точный текст эксепшена у вас отсутствует, сюрпрайз! придётся спрашивать входные данные и собирать информацию о том, на каком компе запускается, ошибка может не воспроизводиться) и переписывать программу.

Во-вторых, вы совершаете ошибку "о чём вижу - о том пою". Посмотрите на строчку "установить фон в красный цвет". Это должен быть отдельный метод, но не с названием "установить цвет в красный цвет", а с названием "УказатьЧтоПроизошлаОшибка". Понимаете, это деталь реализации, как именно указать, а смысл этой строки - именно указать, что произошла ошибка. (Строка ResetColor становится методом "СброситьСтатусОшибки").
Читая в коде программы название вызываемого метода вы получите намного более понятный код.

В-третьих, комментарии уберите. Вообще. Хороший код должен быть понятен сам по себе (перечитайте второй пункт моего ответа, если непонятно). Не нужно указывать смысл действий - он должен быть понятен из кода человеку, который знает синтаксис языка)

Это навскидку, я вообще не планировал ответ на вопрос давать, я из очереди проверок пришёл.

PS Ещё один вариант разделения программы на смысловые блоки. Разделены операции ввода, вывода, валидации, расчёта. Сделано в расчёте на вашу зону ближайшего развития.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            ShowInitialMessage();
            var input = EnterUserInput();
            ValidateRequest(input);
            var request = PrepareData(input);
            var result = Calculate(request);
            ShowResult(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Произошла ошибка: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private static void ShowInitialMessage()
    {
        Console.Write("Inter Summa / Procent / Mounth ");
    }

    private static string EnterUserInput()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ValidateRequest(string input)
    {
        var result = input.Split();

        if(result.Length != 3)
            throw new Exception("Введите 3 значения через пробел");

        double notUsed;
        for(var i = 0; i<2; i++)
        {
            if(!double.TryParse(result[i], out notUsed)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Значение № {i+1} не является валидным числом");
            }
        }
    }

    private static Request PrepareData(string input)
    {
        var splitted = input.Split();
        return new Request
        {
            Summa = double.Parse(splitted[0]),
            Proc = double.Parse(splitted[1]),
            Time = double.Parse(splitted[2]),
        };
    }

    public static double Calculate(Request request)
    {
        return Math.Round(request.Summa * Math.Pow((1 + request.Proc / 1200), request.Time));
    }

    private static void ShowResult(double result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Результат расчёта: {result} .руб");
    }
}

public class Request
{
    public double Summa { get; set; }

    public double Proc { get; set; }

    public double Time { get; set; }
}
```

Отличий от вашей программы два:

- после того, как отработана программа не нужно запускать её снова. Во-первых, потому что это не её обязанность (программа должна пройти от ввода данных через расчёт данных и их вывод), во-вторых, потому что у вас нет кода для выхода (спросить "хотите пройти расчёт ещё раз?")
- я убрал форматирование цветов, не люблю излишнюю пёстроту в консоли. Свой совет я по этому поводу дал, а пример есть в соседнем ответе у @tym32167