# Корректировка кода консольного калькулятора на C#

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

У меня есть код консольного калькулятора, написан на C#, сделан в целях изучения. Не давно перешел на этот язык с Java, кружечка с кофе мне не подходила под интересы, программирую 2 года, но знаете, как-то все странно получалось, я скорее не старался понять язык, а изучил основы и дальше все на ходу доучивал, если кратко занимался разработкой чисто для релакса (хз как это, но это именно так) и неважно. В связи с тем, что я решил перейти на другой язык, мне показалось интересным начать именно изучать язык и понимать, как и что работает, а не писать говнокод. Я прошу у вас, программистов со стажем, посмотреть мой код и указать на ошибки или не логические действия, может где-то какую-то строку нужно убрать и заменить другой и т.п. В общем прошу, если не составит труда, направить меня на мои ошибки.
Вот код:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        private static int A;
        private static int B;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartProgramm();
            Close();
        }

        private static void StartProgramm()//полагает начало программы
        {
            MathGetNumber();
            MathOperation();
        }

        private static void MathGetNumber()//получаем число
        {
            string AT;
            string BT;

            Console.WriteLine("Первое число");
            AT = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Второе число");
            BT = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                A = Convert.ToInt32(AT);
                B = Convert.ToInt32(BT);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Не шали, вводи только числа!");
                StartProgramm();
            }

            for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)//это я решил сделать отступ в несколько строк
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static void MathOperation()//производим операцию с числом
        {
            byte Operate;
            string Operation;

            if (A == 0 && B == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Числа имеют значение 0, продолжать работу программы нет смысла, завершение");
            }
            else
            {
                const byte Longe = 4;
                byte OperNum = 1;
                char[] NumUs = new char[Longe] { '+', '-', '*', ':' };
                Console.WriteLine("Числа имеют значение > или < 0, выберите желаемую операцию над числом");

                for (byte i = 0; i < Longe; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(OperNum + ") " + NumUs[i]);
                    OperNum++;
                }

                Operation = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    Operate = Convert.ToByte(Operation);

                    if (Operate <= 4)
                    {

                        switch (Operate)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A + B));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A - B));
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A * B));
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A / B));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Хватит шалить, вводи число от 1 до 4 включительно");
                        MathOperation();
                    }
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Хватит шалить, вводи число от 1 до 4 включительно");
                    MathOperation();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ReturnProgramm()//повторение работы программы с самого начала, на случай если пользователь захочет еще раз посчитать число 
        {
                StartProgramm();
                Close();
            }
        }

        private static void Close()//завершение работы программы
        {
            string answer;

            Console.WriteLine("Close program? y/n");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer == "y")
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (answer == "n")
            {
                ReturnProgramm();
            }
            else
            {
                Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. чего вам не хватает [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc), следующее на что следует посмотреть, это применение[Патернов проектирования кода](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/), ну и конечно методология [SOLID](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/5.1.php). Ну и конечно учиться хорошему - сразу осваивать написание тестов!

Comment: Недавно было что то подобное, там полноценно описали какие ошибки, как стоит поступать и так далее. Советую [почитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982999/220553).

Comment: спасибо, ребят, обязательно все почитаю

Comment: `Program` пишется с одной буквой `m`.

Comment: Попробуйте статический анализ. Откройте в Visual Studio свойства проекта. Вкладка Code Analysis. Чекните Enable Code Analysis on Build. Выберите в комбобоксе набор правил (ставьте сразу Microsoft All Rules). Скомпилируйте проект. Будет большущий список ошибок-предупреждений. Изучайте ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще каждый программист находит для себя свой стиль. Важно лишь соблюдать базовые принципы, заложенные той или иной технологией.

Мой ответ будет основан исключительно на собственном опыте и может не совпадать с мнением других.

**Первое**, что сразу бросилось в глаза - это **методы без параметров и возвращаемых значений**. Да, есть методы, которые могут быть без параметров и не возвращать ничего (собственно, ваши методы `StartProgram()` и `Close()`). Но вот лично мне хотелось бы, чтобы метод `MathGetNumber()` возвращал значение, а не присваивал его какой-то глобальной переменной. Желательно, чтобы метод получал необходимые значения, проводил с ними определенные манипуляции и в случае необходимости возвращал значение. Если хотите все же оставить метод таким, то тогда лучше было бы его назвать, например, так: `MathReadAB()`. Старайтесь, чтобы ваш метод делал ровно то, о чем говорит его название.

**Второе**: в C# в классах **private-поля** принято именовать **с маленькой буквы**:

```
private static int a;
```

а еще некоторые программисты к private-полям добавляют приставку с нижним подчеркиванием (это уже дело вкуса; при стандартных настройках Visual Studio подсказками предлагает именно такой вариант именования):

```
private static int _a;
```

Для C#, как и для любого другого ЯП, есть [соглашение по именованию членов, переменных, функций...](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) и [соглашение по написанию кода](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions).

**Третье:** не пытайтесь сэкономить на памяти, объявляя вместо `int` переменную типа `byte`. Это, может быть, и хорошо, однако излишняя оптимизация часто не оправдана. В данном случае, мне кажется, она не оправдана. К тому же, если вы проявите невнимательность, то тип `byte` может переполниться без вашего ведома, что может привести к непредсказуемым результатам работы программы. В мировой практике для итераторов цикла и любых других счетчиков принято брать тип `int`.

**Четвертое:** В методе `MathOperation()` можно избавиться от лишних фигурных скобок, заменив

```
if (A == 0 && B == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Числа имеют значение 0, продолжать работу программы нет смысла, завершение");
}
else
{
    //else-code
}
```

на

```
if (A == 0 && B == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Числа имеют значение 0, продолжать работу программы нет смысла, завершение");
    return;
}

//else-code
```

Это довольно частая и хорошая практика, иначе если у вас в коде будет много проверок, будет много вложенных `else` и фигурных скобок, что ухудшает читаемость кода.

**Пятое:** Это чисто логическая ошибка. Если у вас `A=1` и `B=0`, то программа продолжит свою работу, что приведет к `DivideByZeroException`. Нужно переделать условие `if (B == 0)`. Этого будет достаточно.

**Шестое:** Вместо конструкции

```
if (Operate <= 4)
{
    switch (Operate)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A + B));
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A - B));
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A* B));
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A / B));
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Хватит шалить, вводи число от 1 до 4 включительно");
    MathOperation();
}
```

лучше воспользоваться `default:`

```
    switch (Operate)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A + B));
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A - B));
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A* B));
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A / B));
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Хватит шалить, вводи число от 1 до 4 включительно");
            MathOperation();
            break;
    }
```

В остальном все хорошо. Только Ваш стиль с объявлением переменных в начале метода - для меня непривычен, но он имеет место быть. Постарался осветить все проблемные места, что увидел.

Comment: студия не предлагает подчеркивание для приватных переменных по умолчанию.

Comment: По поводу четвёртого пункта. Во многих руководствах считается, что методы (и циклы) должны иметь одну точку выхода, поэтому нельзя использовать `return` таким способом. Более того, во многих языках программирования `return` вообще отсутствует, именно по этой причине. Но лично я его использую. Просто довожу до общего сведения.

Comment: @Grundy В Community-версии действительно по умолчанию нет такого поведения. У меня на 2015 Professional вроде бы по умолчанию стояли эти подсказки. Я еще приду домой и проверю это

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov соглашусь с вами. Очень часто встречал такие методики и сам стараюсь их придерживаться, но вот в подобных случаях хочется избежать лишних объявлений переменных и лишней вложенности.

Comment: Благодарю, все четко и без воды. Постараюсь учесть все выше сказанное)

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение:

```
A = Convert.ToInt32(AT);
B = Convert.ToInt32(BT);
```

При использовании методов класса Convert единственный способ обработки неверного ввода - исключения. Генерация исключений является несколько тяжелой операцией, поэтому лучше использовать метод TryParse.

```
Console.WriteLine("Числа имеют значение 0, продолжать работу программы нет смысла, завершение");
```

Такая проверка не имеет смысла, арифметические операции с нолями вполне допустимы (кроме деления). 0+0 должно выдавать 0, а не ошибку.

```
char[] NumUs = new char[Longe] { '+', '-', '*', ':' };
//...
for (byte i = 0; i < Longe; i++)
```

Если массив зашит в коде, нет смысла также зашивать в коде его константную длину. Длину массива можно определить программно методом Length, так что при добавлении элементов не придется менять код в двух местах

```
Console.WriteLine("Хватит шалить, вводи число от 1 до 4 включительно");
```

Вы предлагаете пользователю ввести число, а затем преобразуете его в символ. Почему бы сразу не вводить символ? Это намного проще и удобнее.

```
Console.WriteLine("Close program? y/n");
answer = Console.ReadLine();
```

Так как вы просите пользователя ввести один из символов, оба из которых требуют одиночного нажатия клавиши, можно сделать его ввод чуть более удобным с использованием Console.ReadKey.

```
private static void StartProgramm()//полагает начало программы
{
    MathGetNumber();
    MathOperation();
}
```

Этот код привносит в программу "повторную входимость": StartProgramm вызывает MathGetNumber, который, в свою очередь, вызывает StartProgramm. Это приводит к тому, что стек вызовов в ходе работы программы будет постепенно расти. Для реализации повторяемости лучше использовать циклы, а не повторно входимые методы.

---

Мой вариант улучшения с учетом этих замечаний:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int A;
        private static int B;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool success;
            while (true)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    success = MathGetNumber();
                    if (success) break;
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    success = MathOperation();
                    if (success) break;
                }                

                if (Close()) break;                 
            }
        }       

        private static bool MathGetNumber()//получаем число
        {
            string AT;
            string BT;

            Console.WriteLine("Первое число");
            AT = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Второе число");
            BT = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Int32.TryParse(AT, out A) == false || Int32.TryParse(BT, out B) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Не шали, вводи только числа!");
                return false;
            }

            for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)//это я решил сделать отступ в несколько строк
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static bool MathOperation()//производим операцию с числом
        {                       

            char[] NumUs = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', ':' };

            Console.WriteLine("Введите один из знаков операций: ");
            for (byte i = 0; i < NumUs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(NumUs[i]+" ");                
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            string sign = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (sign)
            {
                case "+":
                    Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A + B));
                    break;
                case "-":
                    Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A - B));
                    break;
                case "*":
                    Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A * B));
                    break;
                case ":":
                    if (B == 0) Console.WriteLine("Делить на ноль нельзя");
                    else Console.WriteLine("Ваше число = " + (A / B));
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Не шали, введи один из допустимых знаков операции!");
                    return false;
            }
            return true;

        }                

        private static bool Close()//завершение работы программы
        {
            char answer;
            Console.WriteLine("Close program? y/n");

            while (true)
            {
                answer = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;

                if (answer == 'y')
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (answer == 'n')
                {
                    return false;
                }                
            }            
        }

    }
}
```