# Как избавиться от лишних перегрузок

Tags: c#, unity3d, перегрузка-функций

Я пишу тайловую карту на Unity. В процессе написания появилось предчувствие, что я делаю что-то не так. Это связано с тем, что я пишу слишком много перегрузок. Вопрос в том, как избавиться от этих перегрузок и нужно ли это делать? Или возможно проблема в другом? Помогите сделать код удобнее. Код с перегрузками:

```
public List<Cell> NeighbordCells(Cell cell, List<Vector3Int> neighbordCellsIndexesOffset) //Основной метод Определение соседних ячеек
{
    List<Cell> rez = new List<Cell>();
    foreach (var neighbordCellIndexOffset in neighbordCellsIndexesOffset)
    {
        var neighdordCellIndex =
            OddrCoordinatesInIndex(cell.positionInOddrCoordinates + neighbordCellIndexOffset);
        if (neighdordCellIndex != -1)
        {
            rez.Add(cells[neighdordCellIndex]);
        }
        else
        {
            rez.Add(null);
        }
    }
    return rez;
}

public List<Cell> NeighbordCells(Tile tile, List<Vector3Int> neighbordCellsIndexesOffset) //Перегрузка 1
{
    return NeighbordCells(tile.Cell, neighbordCellsIndexesOffset);
}

public List<Cell> NeighbordCells(List<Tile> tiles, List<Vector3Int> neighbordCellsIndexesOffset) //Перегрузка 2
{
    var neighbordCells = new List<Cell>();
    foreach (var tile in tiles)
    {
        neighbordCells.AddRange(NeighbordCells(tile, neighbordCellsIndexesOffset));
    }
}

public List<Cell> NeighbordCells(List<Cell> cells, List<Vector3Int> neighbordCellsIndexesOffset) //Перегрузка 3
{
    var neighbordCells = new List<Cell>();
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        neighbordCells.AddRange(NeighbordCells(cell, neighbordCellsIndexesOffset));
    }
}
```

Недавно познакомился с обобщениями (дженериками), возможно перегрузки 2 и 3 можно объединить с помощью них, но как это правильно сделать, пока не понимаю.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Перегрузка методов это не лишнее. Лишнее это то без чего ваше приложение и его использующие могут работать не используя. Перегрузка обычно создается из потребностей и принципа SOLID конкретнее принципа О - Принцип открытости/закрытости. Поскольку вносить изменения в существующий код не рекомендуется то в следствии появляется перегрузки.

Comment: Согласен с началом ответа, не со всем согласен с его окончанием. Особенно не согласен с этим `Поскольку вносить изменения в существующий код не рекомендуется`. Чуть подробнее про О [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889202/179763).

Comment: @tym32167 Огромное спасибо за ваш комментарий и отличный ответ про О.

Comment: @ВладРудницкий пожалуйста!