# Передача объекта интерфейса в конструктор JAVA

Tags: java

```
public class CalculatorWithAutoAggregationSetup1  implements ICalculator {
    ICalculator ic;
    CalculatorWithOperator cwo;
    public CalculatorWithAutoAggregationSetup1(ICalculator ic) {
        this.ic = ic;

    }
    private int counter;
    private long memory;

    public CalculatorWithAutoAggregationSetup1() {

    }


    public double divide(double a, double b) {
        counter++;
        return ic.divide(a,b);
    }

    public double multiplication(double a, double b) {
        counter++;
        return a * b;
    }

    public double plus(double a, double b) {
        counter++;
        return a + b;
    }

    public double minus(double a, double b) {
        counter++;
        return a - b;
    }

    public double square(double a, int b) {
        double square = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            square *= a;
        }
        counter++;
        return square;
    }

    public double module(double a) {
        if (a < 0) {
            a = -(a);
        }
        counter++;
        return a;
    }

    public double root(double a) {
        double x;
        if (a<0) {
            a = -(a);
        }
        double half = a / 2;
        do {
            x = half;
            half = (x + (a / x)) / 2;
        } while ((x - half) != 0);
        counter++;
        return half;
    }
    public long getCounter() {
        return  counter;
    }
```

Не могу понять, если мы передаём объект типа ICalculator, то в main мы должны будем его создать(как я понимаю), но объект интерфейса нельзя создать без реализации его методов. Плюс надо делегировать методы без собственной математике, но как я понимаю делегировать без другого класса я не могу, и интерфейсом в том числе(т.к. он без реализации). Вопрос в том, что я должен передать в конструктор, точнее каким образом (ICalculator обязательно передать), чтобы я мог и делегировать методы и мог запустить main.

Comment: Есть такой паттерн - декоратор, почитайте про него тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740596/179763 или тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889202/179763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

слышал что-нибудь про полиморфизм? один интерфейс - множество реализаций?

если кратко, интерфейс - это контракт, гарантирующий, что у нас будет определённое поведение, т.е. мы на 100% уверены, что в любом классе реализующем интерфейс будет нужный метод.

```
interface Speakable {
    void speak();
}
```

и создадим три класса и у каждого будет свой метод speak

```
class Cat implements Speakable {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("мяу");
    }
}

class Dog implements Speakable {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("гав");
    }
}

class Developer implements Speakable {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("учу джаву");
    }
}
```

и в мейне можем создать обьект через интерфейс

```
Speakable speakable = new Developer();
Speakable speakableCat = new Cat();
Speakable speakableDog = new Dog();
```

мы можем создать метод принимающий любой объект Speakable, т.к. мы знаем что у него будет метод speak, и в будущем сможем создавать и добавлять любые реализации не переписывая текущий код.

```
void test(Speakable speakable) {
        speakable.speak();
    }
```

Коллекции тоже через интерфейс создаются.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //лист обьектов реализующих контракт Speakable
        List<Speakable> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Cat()); 
        list.add(new Dog());  
        list.add(new Developer());

        for (Speakable speakable : list) {
            speakable.speak();
        }
    }
```

вывод

```
мяу
гав
учу джаву
```

если не создавать обьекты, то передать в метод анонимный класс либо лямбду . это должен быть функциональный интерфейс с одним абстрактным методом.

```
public class Test {

    static void test(Speakable speakable) {
        speakable.speak();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(new Speakable() {
            @Override
            public void speak() {
                System.out.println("через анонимный класс");
            }
        });

        test(() -> System.out.println("через лямбду"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Это хорошо, на один вопрос я получил ответ. Теперь про второй, в методах как я изложил выше, требуется произвести расчёты не математикой, а делегировать другим калькулятором переданным в конструктор(но объекты в классе создавать нельзя). У меня есть 2-ой класс реализующий этот же интерфейс, с такими же методами, но я не могу создать объект, чтобы передать методы 2-го калькулятора. Поэтому, что в данном случае сделать я не понимаю.

Comment: сейчас в ответ добавлю

Comment: Тут чуть-чуть по-другому. main класс у меня отдельно, в нём я могу создавать объекты, но мне требуется делегировать методы из другого калькулятора. Например у меня есть класс CalculatorWithOperator и при композиции я мог бы создать объект этого класса с именем  cwo, и в методах данного класса я мог бы вызывать методы 2-го класса. Тоже самое я как понимаю я должен сделать в конструкторе, но без создания объекта в данном классе.

Comment: сам хоть понимаешь что тебе надо? делегировать методы - передай лямбду или анонимный класс, вызвать методы 2 класса -  cоздай статик методы и вызывай их через класс или  создай в классе поле с другим классом и вызови у него метод другого класса, или воспользуйся паттерном адаптер или декоратор . Видишь сколько вариантов и я в душе не знаю что такое cwo и что оно должно делать. учись формулировать кратко и тезисно вопрос типа класс А и В как вызвать метод А из класса В. а делегировать методы класса из другого ты можешь любым из описанных выше вариантов